# Updating uicollectionview when core data object changes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to convert a table view to a collection view. I have it display the cells fine but any changes made to them aren't being displayed until i leave the view/come back or scroll the cell off screen. The data comes from core data

The first cell is being update correctly, but the other cells aren't. If i update again, they get updated but only to the value of the previous update. I can see the update function being called but the configure cell isn't being called to actually update the contents, only on the first cell

Full code here: http://pastebin.com/BDaVS6vq

The results of the nslogs give

> // View initial load 2016-05-18 15:03:38.012 Calona[1304:315892] 3.
>   Pet: Optional("Pea") - Exp: Optional(2000) 2016-05-18 15:03:38.022
>   Calona[1304:315892] 3. Pet: Optional("Squi") - Exp: Optional(2000)
>   2016-05-18 15:03:38.033 Calona[1304:315892] 3. Pet: Optional("Whisper
>   Light") - Exp: Optional(2000)
>
> // After first update 2016-05-18 15:06:12.686 Calona[1309:316804] 1.
>   User Pet: Optional("Pea") 2016-05-18 15:06:12.698 Calona[1309:316804]
>   2. Update 2016-05-18 15:06:12.705 Calona[1309:316804] 3. Pet: Optional("Pea") - Exp: Optional(4000) 2016-05-18 15:06:12.710
>   Calona[1309:316804] 3. Pet: Optional("Squi") - Exp: Optional(3000)
>   2016-05-18 15:06:12.714 Calona[1309:316804] 3. Pet: Optional("Whisper
>   Light") - Exp: Optional(3000) 2016-05-18 15:06:12.725
>   Calona[1309:316804] 1. User Pet: Optional("Squi") 2016-05-18
>   15:06:12.732 Calona[1309:316804] 2. Update 2016-05-18 15:06:12.737
>   Calona[1309:316804] 1. User Pet: Optional("Whisper Light") 2016-05-18
>   15:06:12.742 Calona[1309:316804] 2. Update 2016-05-18 15:06:12.895
>   Calona[1309:316804] 2. Update 2016-05-18 15:06:12.895
>   Calona[1309:316804] 2. Update
>
> After second update 2016-05-18 15:06:26.903 Calona[1309:316804] 1.
>   User Pet: Optional("Pea") 2016-05-18 15:06:26.918 Calona[1309:316804]
>   2. Update 2016-05-18 15:06:26.924 Calona[1309:316804] 3. Pet: Optional("Pea") - Exp: Optional(5000) 2016-05-18 15:06:26.931
>   Calona[1309:316804] 3. Pet: Optional("Squi") - Exp: Optional(4000)
>   2016-05-18 15:06:26.936 Calona[1309:316804] 3. Pet: Optional("Whisper
>   Light") - Exp: Optional(4000) 2016-05-18 15:06:26.945
>   Calona[1309:316804] 1. User Pet: Optional("Squi") 2016-05-18
>   15:06:26.952 Calona[1309:316804] 2. Update 2016-05-18 15:06:26.958
>   Calona[1309:316804] 1. User Pet: Optional("Whisper Light") 2016-05-18
>   15:06:26.962 Calona[1309:316804] 2. Update 2016-05-18 15:06:27.045
>   Calona[1309:316804] 2. Update 2016-05-18 15:06:27.047
>   Calona[1309:316804] 2. Update 2016-05-18 15:06:27.048
>   Calona[1309:316804] 2. Update

Comment: Can you confirm that you reach the statement of this `if let results = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` condition ?

Comment: yeah, that line is fine, and everything within the if goes ahead

Comment: It might be a thread problem (you use NSBlockOperation that use a high priority queue  but what you need is a dispatch_async with the main queue)

Comment: all the information i can find shows that you have to use block operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used the code available here and its working

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jonzhan/e821b7c7fbd13f736768/raw/b84db699779a383506704ecc92814a185502a69f/UICollection%2520and%2520NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate%2520integration.swift

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that are missing these lines in the `viewDidLoad` of your `ViewController`:

```
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
```

and try to use :

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
        self?.blockOperation.start();
        }, completion: { (success) -> Void in
            ...
    })
}
```

and I also defined:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.blockOperation = NSBlockOperation();
}
```

Comment: its set in IB. The data is being populated into cells, just not updated when the core data object changes

Comment: yes, the delegate is being set. The problem appears to be with the func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) method at the moment. The method is being called but none the the options in the switch are being triggered and if i print the type i get 'NSFetchedResultsChangeType' which doesn't match any switch options

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: Try to set `_fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self` immediately before return it.